# How to access and set static property value in TestMethod

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How to access and set `StaticProperty`

```
public static class StaticClass
{
  private bool? _staticValue = null;
  public bool StaticProperty => _staticValue ?? ((bool)(_staticValue = GetStaticPropertyValue()));

  public static bool GetStaticPropertyValue()
  {
    //get value
  }
}
```

inside Test Method,

```
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTestSomeMethod()
{
    var consumeClass = new ConsumeClass();
    consumeClass.SomeMethod();
}
```

so that `isEnabled` variable is set to true in `ConsumeClass.SomeMethod`

```
public class ConsumeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var isEnabled = StaticClass.StaticProperty;
        
        if(isEnabled)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can´t, as it has no setter. Either define a public setter for the property as well, or use reflection.

Comment: While I suspect that the example has been simplified to make it easier to understand,  this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: There are code-smells in the shown example that are the direct cause of the problems being encountered. Review the current design and refactor the code to make it testable.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i have not included entire property before, my bad

Comment: @Nkosi by looking at the latest update do you still think it has code smell?

Comment: kindly explain downvoting, i can explain more clearer if required

Comment: @tabby yes it still does. It would be awesome if you could reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @tabby take some time and properly edit the question. The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: @tabby Why don't you define an other method `SetStaticProperty(){_staticValue = true;}` to and call this method accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

The way your code currently looks like there´s only a dirty way using reflection, because there´s no setter for your property:

```
var property = typeof(StaticClass).GetProperty("StaticProperty", BindingFlags.Static)?.GetBackingField().SetValue(null, true);
```

This sometimes is neccessary for large legacy-systems that you can´t easily change but you have the need for unit-tests. However you should change the system as soon as possible, e.g. by using an `internal` setter:

```
public static bool StaticProperty { get; internal set; }
```

and add the `InternalsVisibleTo`-attribute to your assemby, in order to access its `internal` members within your test-assembly.

As per your edit the reflection-based approach is a bit easier, as you have a named backing-field which you can assign a new value:

```
typeof(StaticClass).GetField("_staticValue", BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, true);
```

However be aware that variable-names may change, so the above may fail at runtime when someone renames the backing-field.